# Replacing dumb quotes for smart quotes with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to swap dumb quotes for their smart equivalent. So I want to turn `Jane said 'How do we do this?' 'I don't know' replied Sam.` into `Jane said ‘How do we do this?’ ‘I don’t know’ replied Sam.` for example.

The apostrophe in `don't` is easy. `preq_replace` with a pattern of `/(\w+)'(\w+)/` will find apostrophes inside words. But I can't swap the speech quotes properly. Currently I have:

```
$singlequotesPattern = "/'(.*)'/";
$singlequotesReplacement = "‘$1’";

$singlequotes = preg_replace($singlequotesPattern, $singlequotesReplacement, $text);
```

But this fails with the above sentence and produces `Jane said ‘How do we do this?' 'I don't know’ replied Sam.` It's only matching the outer most single quotes. How can I make it replace both pairs of quotes?

Comment: [SmartyPants](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-smartypants/) is a free web publishing tool that translates plain ASCII punctuation characters into “smart” typographic punctuation HTML entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$singlequotesPattern = "/'(.*?)'/";
```

Add a `?` to make the `*` quantifier non-greedy. A greedy quantifier finds the longest match possible. A non-greedy one finds the shortest.

Greedy:

```
Jane said 'How do we do this?' 'I don’t know' replied Sam.
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Non-greedy:

```
Jane said 'How do we do this?' 'I don’t know' replied Sam.
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```