# How to use same string (character) with PHP str_replace to open and close tag?

Tags: php, str-replace

I need to make members on my site able to enter code using the string ` and close it with the same string ` as we can do here in StackOverflow.

Here is the code that I have used

```
function replace_text($text) {
    $text = str_replace('`', '<code>', $text);
    $text = str_replace('`', '<\code>', $text);
    return $text;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text');
```

The problem is that only the first string ` is replaced and then `<code>` tag is not closing.

Comment: You might also want to look for a complete PHP mark down parser. Think about code could contain the backtick ``'`'`` itself. It's not an easy implementation.

Comment: @Stender that should be posted as answer.

Comment: @pr1nc3 - Nicks answer is much better, so I would rather just delete it, than post it as an answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17135260/2943403

Comment: @Hamed what do you want to happen if code has a backtick inside of it?  It will break your parser if not handled.

Comment: @mickmackusa Exact, this is a primary code and I was planning to look for a solution for this. Nick suggested one, but unfortunately is not working on my site.

Comment: Use Nick's Demo link(s) to explain your issue to us.  Paste your input string that causes problems into Nick's code, then run it and send us back the updated demo link.  I don't understand how Nick's solution is not what you want.  And using slashes to escape backticks is how backticks are escaped on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using `preg_replace` instead:

```
function replace_text($text) {
    return preg_replace('/`([^`]*)`/', '<code>$1</code>', $text);
}
```

for example:

```
$text = 'some words and `some code` and some more words';
echo replace_text($text);
```

Output:

```
some words and <code>some code</code> and some more words
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/4qZZM)

**Update**

If you are worried about the possibility of there being escaped backticks in the text, you can use this regex instead, which checks that the first backtick is not escaped using a negative lookbehind, and then ignores any escaped backticks within the delimiting ones:

```
function replace_text($text) {
    return preg_replace('/(?<!\\\\)`((?:[^`\\\\]|\\\\.)*)`/', '<code>$1</code>', $text);
}
```

another example:

```
$text = 'some words \` and `some code` and `some \`more code` again';
echo replace_text($text);
```

Output:

```
some words \` and <code>some code</code> and <code>some \`more code</code> again
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Ck0co)

**Update 2**

To also replace any `` \` `` in the string, we add a second pair of pattern & replacement to the call to `preg_match`:

```
function replace_text($text) {
    return preg_replace(array('/(?<!\\\\)`((?:[^`\\\\]|\\\\.)*)`/', '/\\\\`/'), array('<code>$1</code>', '`'), $text);
}

$text = 'some words \` and `some code` and `some \`more code` again';
echo replace_text($text);
```

Output:

```
some words ` and <code>some code</code> and <code>some `more code</code> again
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/mgtkm)

Comment: What if someone wants to escape a backtick so that it is not treated as a special character? This is a reasonable fringe case.

Comment: @mickmackusa good point... will fix...

Comment: @Nick Thanks man, this works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52763438/regex-to-delete-post-quotes?r=SearchResults#comment92451998_52763869

Comment: @mickmackusa alternate solution to deal with escaped backticks posted.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/MjRaP your negated character class is the problem.

Comment: @Nick, Unfortunately, your updated solution is not working for me, the code begin from the last backtick, and is it possible to give a solution that enables displaying the backtick without displaying the backslash.

Comment: @Hamed can you give me an example of text that isn't working?

Comment: @mickmackusa problem was I was only checking for escaped backtick instead of any escaped character. Answer and demo updated. https://3v4l.org/Ck0co

Comment: @Nick I'm sorry, it seems that it was a bug related to caching or maybe something else that I didn't catch. So I can say that your code works, thank you. But, still looking to get a solution to [display backticks without the backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54354602/how-to-escape-a-backtick-with-a-backslash-in-a-php-function-which-allows-to?noredirect=1#comment95527178_54354602).

Comment: @Hamed see my edit, that should do what you want

Comment: @Nick Yes! Yes! This is exactly what I want. Thank you again man.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in a way respecting the possibility that codes could contain some backticks as well.

To achieve that you can use a regular expression with capturing groups and a backreference. The first capturing group `` (`+) `` takes at least one backtick and as many as available in order to the quantifier `+`. Then all the following characters are captured in group 2. The backreference `\1` (string encoded with escaped backslash as `'\\1'`) requires as many backticks as captured in group 1.

```
$s = 'Some ``code containing the backtick ` character`` should `work` as well.';

$tagged = preg_replace('~(`+)(.*?)\\1~us', '<code>$2</code>', $s);
```

result:

```
Some <code>code containing the backtick ` character</code> should <code>work</code> as well.
```

However, I recommend using a complete markdown parser, which can be found as open source library on the web.

Comment: What about \`text escaped \\` text\`?

Comment: @mickmackusa I do not feel to provide too many extra features not asked in the question since there can be found many well implemented markdown parsers as open source out there. No need to reinvent the wheel. Escaping the backtick could be a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work - it avoids performance overheads of regexp (if you care about that sort of thing) and can give feedback if you have unclosed blocks):

```
while (strpos($text, '`')) {
    $firstOccurence = strpos($text, '`');
    $text = substr_replace($text, '<code>', $firstOccurence, 1);
    $secondOccurence = strpos($text, '`');
    if ($secondOccurence !== false) {
        $text = substr_replace($text, '</code>', $secondOccurence, 1);
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Unclosed block');
    }
}
```

Example here:

https://repl.it/@abulafia/SparseLoathsomeExtensions

This continues parsing the text while there are ticks to be found. `str_pos` identifies the position of the first tick, and then we replace it using `substr_replace`. We then repeat this procedure, but if there's no second tick, throw an exception (or do whatever you want!)